# How to show only some part of `selectedValue` in `Picker` in react-native?

Tags: react-native, picker

I am implementing Picker in react-native. The Picker values are String. I need to show only a part of that String in selected value and I need to split that string and get data out of it dynamically.

```
<Picker selectedValue={() => this.state.item.unit[this.state.uIndex].split(/\d+(cals)/)[0]} 
                       style={style.pick}


                       onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({uIndex: itemIndex})}
                       mode="dropdown"
                    >
                    {
                       this.state.item.unit.map((sizee) => {
                           return( <Picker.Item label={sizee} value={sizee} /> );
                       })
                   }
                   </Picker>
```

The above code changes the state of `uIndex` and works fine if I write `selectedValue` in the following way:

```
selectedValue={this.state.item.unit[this.state.uIndex]}
```

How do I show splitted value ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split it before sending it to the picker:

//create a new array with the splitted values to replace the original one

```
var arrayWithSplittedStrings=[];
 this.state.item.unit.map(item=>{
    let eachItemSplitted = item.split(/\d+(cals)/)[0]
    arrayWithSplittedStrings.push(eachItemSplitted )
})
//then replace your state with the splitted values
this.setState({item[unit]:arrayWithSplittedStrings})
```

then it should work the way you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rodrigo . I want to show the original string array in picker options. I just want to split the selected value String dynamically. When the user picks up a value, then selected value should be shown the String by splitting the picked value. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: In that case you should push an object into the array containing the original string and the splitted string:
replace this line with this: 
  arrayWithSplittedStrings.push({splitted:eachItemSplitted,string:item} )
then your picker should be like this:

this.state.item.unit.map((item) => {
                           return( <Picker.Item label={item.string} value={item.splitted} /> );
                       })

let me know if it solves your problem